# Creating circle polygons for 'Protection Zones' that are specific to individual points measured by radius in metres using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, expression, syntax

I have found similar questions to this but nothing that will work for my particular circumstance.

I have points as a vector layer, I want to display their measured protection zones that are individual to each point and are provided in metre measurements.

I have approached this by trying to create an expression however, my QGIS knowledge isn't great at the moment and I am still learning syntax.

Comment: For what i understand you need buffers (menu / vector / geometry / buffer); at the buffer prompt there's the distance value and next to it an icon for choosing a variable for distance; just check it is a numeric variable

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 2):

You can symbolize your point layer using the geometry generator. (I have a field called area, so I calculate buffer radius with sqrt( "area"/pi()) ). The five is number of segments, higher = rounder

[image]

If you want to create a permanent polygon layer with the buffers use [Vector - Geoprocessing tools - Buffer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisbuffer), or [geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisgeometrybyexpression)